# Can i create an Evernote add-on that is integrated with the Evernote UI on Mac?

Tags: macos, evernote, evernote-app-notebook

I have an idea for an Evernote Add-on and will start the programming process next week, but am not sure if it can actually be supported. I basically want to create an app that can be toggled on/off from the Evernote Interface through clicking the app icon, similar to the Google Drive Icon in the UI. Once turned on, when a user selects certain references in their notes, my add-on would provide a pop-up screen. This screen will contain information with a few additional features. Does the Evernote API support the ability to add an icon to the Evernote UI, and for pop-up screens to be shown from the Evernote UI?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, Evernote doesn't have an add-on mechanism.